# Не работает путь к картинке background-image

Tags: html, css

```css
.top {
  background-image: url("https://w-dog.net/wallpapers/2/4/332444738754522.jpg");
}
```

```html
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="maindiv"></div>
<div class="footdiv"></div>
```

Пересмотрел похожие вопросы, ответа так и не нашел. Картинка не отображается. Css подключил правильно (проверял заданием цвета фона). Путь задавал и с одинарными кавычками и без них.

Comment: @entithat папка в которой изображение на одном уровне с папкой css

Comment: @entithat только этот все удалил

Comment: Ну так и понятно, что у блока не указана ширина и высота, поэтому картинку и не видно.

Comment: @entithat подскажите как правильно указать

Comment: Даже попробуйте ради примера указать любое значение, 150 на 150, чтобы проверить работает ли в таком случаи.

Comment: @entithat благодарю всё заработало, извините за возможно глупый вопрос.

Comment: Не бывает глупых вопросов, бывают глупые ответы:))

Comment: Или путь или картинка , пробуй другую картинку добавить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас проблема не с картинкой, а с тем, что вы не задали высоту и ширину.